# Have premade tests that I must write the code for. Can get code to work but wont pass tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I am still new to this. Three months in on learning javascript. So any sort of push in the write direction would be helpful!

So I am currently working on an assignment and it is the first time we are working with tests. The tests are premade for us we just need to write the code and pass the tests. I am having an issue with passing the test even tho my code is doing what the tests are checking for.

```
const inquirer = require('inquirer');


class Employee {

    constructor(name, id, email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
    }

    getName() {
        return inquirer.prompt([
            {
            type: 'input',
            name: 'name',
            message: "What is the employee's name?"
            }
        ]).then(answers => {
            this.name = answers.name;
            this.getId();
        })
    }

    getId() {
        return inquirer.prompt([
            {
                type: 'number',
                name: 'id',
                message: "What is the employee's ID?"
            }
        ]).then(answers => {
            this.id = answers.id;
            this.getEmail();
        })
    }

    getEmail(){
        return inquirer.prompt([
            {
                type: 'input',
                name: 'email',
                message: "What is the employee's email?"
            }
        ]).then(answers => {
            this.email = answers.email;
            this.getRole();
        })
    }

    getRole(){
        this.role = 'employee'
        console.log(this)
    }
}

const e = new Employee();
e.getName();
```

The test looks like this.

```
const Employee = require("../lib/Employee");

test("Can instantiate Employee instance", () => {
  const e = new Employee();
  expect(typeof(e)).toBe("object");
});

test("Can set name via constructor arguments", () => {
  const name = "Alice";
  const e = new Employee(name);
  expect(e.name).toBe(name);
});

test("Can set id via constructor argument", () => {
  const testValue = 100;
  const e = new Employee("Foo", testValue);
  expect(e.id).toBe(testValue);
});

test("Can set email via constructor argument", () => {
  const testValue = "test@test.com";
  const e = new Employee("Foo", 1, testValue);
  expect(e.email).toBe(testValue);
});

test("Can get name via getName()", () => {
  const testValue = "Alice";
  const e = new Employee(testValue);
  expect(e.getName()).toBe(testValue);
});

test("Can get id via getId()", () => {
  const testValue = 100;
  const e = new Employee("Foo", testValue);
  expect(e.getId()).toBe(testValue);
});

test("Can get email via getEmail()", () => {
  const testValue = "test@test.com";
  const e = new Employee("Foo", 1, testValue);
  expect(e.getEmail()).toBe(testValue);
});

test("getRole() should return \"Employee\"", () => {
  const testValue = "Employee";
  const e = new Employee("Alice", 1, "test@test.com");
  expect(e.getRole()).toBe(testValue);
});
```

when I run the code it creates an object with all the answers from the asked questions but the test just returns that it failed because **Employee is not a constructor**

Anyone got some hints or a way to steer me to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you figured it out but i had the same issue. The problem was you have to add module.exports = Employee;
otherwise it can't be used in other files.
hope this helps.